# How to select the textbox in data template

Tags: windows-phone-7

while programming for windows phone 7, I created a listbox and using DataTemplate which contains a textblock and a textbox. The textbox is hided by default.

The XAML:

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="460" Height="60" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}" FontSize="30" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
                    <TextBox Height="60" Width="460" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**The effect I wanna accomplish is : Tap textblock to hide textblock while show textbox.**

CODE BEHIND:

```
private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock.Visibilty = Visibility.Collapsed;
        TextBox.Visibilty = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

However, obviously the selector isn't correct. I tried to add Name for textbox and textblock, but Name seems does not work in Data Template. Is there anyone who can tell me how can i select the textblock and textbox in a Data Template please? Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Name on the template does work, but you can't access it directly!

Instead, try it like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="460" Height="60" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding data}" FontSize="30" Margin="10,10,10,0" Tap="MyTextBlock_Tap" />
                <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Height="60" Width="460" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code:

```
private void MyTextBlock_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var elem = (FrameworkElement)sender;

    var myTextBlock = (TextBlock)elem.FindName("MyTextBlock");
    var myTextBox = (TextBox)elem.FindName("MyTextBox");

    myTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    myTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: hi Pedro, I tried your code but Visual Studio report errors for GetTemplateChild. Did I miss something?

Comment: This time the code works terrific!! You really saved my ass, Man:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<ListBox Name="lst"  >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="460" Height="60" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Tap="Canvas_Tap">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="30" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                            <TextBox Height="60" Width="460" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="text"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void Canvas_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            var m = (sender as Canvas).Children;

            foreach (UIElement x in m)
            {
                if ((x as TextBlock) != null)
                    (x as TextBlock).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                if ((x as TextBox) != null)
                    (x as TextBox).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I tried your code and find it also works great. I love you guys! lol